# Rails конфликт URI.encode и Ajax

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails, form, request

У меня есть строка поиска, которая через мой контроллер, подключается к моей написанной библиотеке, и отправляет get запрос на стороннее api.
Форма:

```
<%= form_with(:url => url_for(:controller => 'orders', :action => 'find_drug'), method: "get") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :drug_name, nil, class: "search_drug", placeholder:"Поиск лекарств..." %>
    <%= button_to "НАЙТИ", nil, class: "search_drug_button" %>
<% end %>
```

Ajax:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.search_drug_button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
                url: 'orders/find_drug',
            }).done(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

Мой метод в контроллере OrdersController:

```
def find_drug
        response = ApiParser::Parser.new
        drugs = response.get_drug(params[:drug_name]).response

        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: drugs.body}
        end
    end
```

Метод в моей библиотеке(написано с помощью гема HTTParty):

```
module ApiParser
    class Parser
        include HTTParty
        ...
        def get_drug(drug)
            options = "?search.drugs={\"ls\": \"#{URI.encode(drug)}\"}"                                 
            self.class.get(options, format: :json)
        end
        ...    
    end
end
```

Отправляются у меня 2 запроса( один из формы, напрямую в контроллер с кодом 200, второй через ajax) и ajax мне выдает ошибку 500

```
NoMethodError in OrdersController#find_drug

undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #305):

#303         unsafe = Regexp.new("[#{Regexp.quote(unsafe)}]", false)
#304       end
*305       str.gsub(unsafe) do
#306         us = $&
#307         tmp = ''
#308         us.each_byte do |uc|

Extracted source (around line #104):

#102     def escape(*arg)
#103       warn "#{caller(1)[0]}: warning: URI.escape is obsolete" if $VERBOSE
*104       DEFAULT_PARSER.escape(*arg)
#105     end
#106     alias encode escape
#107     #

Extracted source (around line #38):

*38             options = "?search.drugs={\"ls\": \"#{URI.encode(drug)}\"}"                                 
#39             self.class.get(options, format: :json)
```

смотря в консоле хрома, какие выполняются запросы
200:

```
...localhost:3000/orders/find_drug?utf8=%E2%9C%93&drug_name=%D1%8F%D1%80%&authenticity_token=Ndao2...
```

500:

```
...localhost:3000/orders/find_drug
```

Если, я в контроллере, вместо params[:drug_name], просто передаю строку, которую хочу найти, срабатывают оба запроса с кодом 200. Написав целиком вопрос, появилась мысль, о том, что мой ajax не получает именно этот params[:drug_name], и не может искать пустое значение. Только начинаю работать c javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

Изменение в контроллере:

```
def find_drug
  response = ApiParser::Parser.new
  @drugs = response.get_drug(params[:drug_name]).response.body
end
```

**код ajax был заменен(удален на)** функциональность(ю) рельсов

изменена форма запроса **form_with(url: '/orders/find_drug', method: :get)**

создан файл в папке orders - **find_drug.js.erb**

в файле find_drug.js.erb - **console.log('<%= @drugs %>');**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.search_drug_button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'orders/find_drug',
      data: new FormData($(this).closest("form")[0])
    }).done(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier : console.log(data);

Comment: @bigidigi89 скобка `{` выпала

Comment: слаб а javascript, поэтому просто код ошибки:  jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at i (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.w.param (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (Аптечная_сеть:551)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)

Comment: добавив processData: false, я вернулся к той же самой ошибке 500